# perform ansible task if string doesn't exist in a multiline register

Tags: ansible, cisco

I want to push configuration for network devices only when that configuration is missing, by searching for a string in the registry output, first I run this task to record the running config on the target device:

```
  # Collect information about the available configuration
- name: Execute show command
  cisco.ios.ios_command:
    commands: 
    - show runn | in repository ## to find if the repository is already configured
  register: output
```

I want to use the output register to conditionally run the below task:

```
- name: Push repository configuration
  cisco.ios.ios_command:
    commands:
    - conf t
    - repository MAIN
    - url ftp://{{ repository_main }}
    - user {{ repository_main_user}} password plain {{ repository_main_password }}
    - exit
    - repository SECONDARY
    - url ftp://{{ repository_sec }}/
    - user {{ repository_sec_user}} password plain {{ repository_sec_password }}
    - end
  when: 'not "MAIN" in {{ output.stdout }} and not "SECONDARY" in {{ output.stdout }}'
```

Here is what output.stdout looks like:

```
TASK [print output] ************************************************************
Saturday 19 November 2022  06:45:44 +0000 (0:00:06.370)       0:00:06.409 ***** 
ok: [node1] => 
  msg:
  - |-
    repository MAIN
    --
    repository SECONDARY
```

When I check the session for the ansible user on the network device I see that it configured the repositories again, which is not what I want, how can I control this? is the fact that the stdout a multiline output a factor here?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the condition

```yaml
      when:
        - "'MAIN' not in output.stdout"
        - "'SECONDARY' not in output.stdout"
```

Test it

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: OK
      when:
        - "'MAIN' not in output.stdout"
        - "'SECONDARY' not in output.stdout"
      vars:
        output:
          stdout: XY

    - debug:
        msg: OK
      when:
        - "'MAIN' not in output.stdout"
        - "'SECONDARY' not in output.stdout"
      vars:
        output:
          stdout: XY MAIN

    - debug:
        msg: OK
      when:
        - "'MAIN' not in output.stdout"
        - "'SECONDARY' not in output.stdout"
      vars:
        output:
          stdout: XY SECONDARY
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: OK

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```